# Can I use User Delegation to sign a SAS token on IoT Hub API

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

Im developing a web application that would allow a user to login with their azure credentials, grant consent on the app to be able to view IoT Hubs and the "things" registered in each hub.  I need to somehow generate a token to be used within the app (on the server side) that would allow me to get a list of things.

My understanding is that I would use a User Delegation SAS in order to achieve this. But I think what Im reading is that this is for containers and blobs. Is this something that is possible with IoT Hubs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I never figured out if this could be done with SAS, but I ended up using the [listkeys](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/iothub/iothubresource/listkeys) API to retrieve the keys.

Comment: Hi Brian, can you mark your answer as answer? Thanks!